# Increase timeout limit gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

When fetching images it returns

````
Fetching image_url is taking a long time time (longer than 15 seconds). This file is File_size MB``` After few of this line it crashes with ```error RequestError: Timeout awaiting 'request' for 30000ms.
````

How can I increase this 15sec timeout limit?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [built-in options](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental/blob/master/docs/plugin-options.md#schemarequestconcurrency-int):

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental`,
  options: {
    schema: {
      requestConcurrency: 50,
    },
  },
},
```

Alternatively you can change your develop running command to, in your `package.json`:

```
"develop": "GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD=5 gatsby develop",
```

Comment: I've already done that still same. ```timeout: 120000, requestConcurrency: 50, perPage: 50``` I'm using this in config.

Comment: Have you tried the second approach (`GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD=5 gatsby develop`)? In one of my projects was the only workin way

Comment: Just tried ```GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD=5 gatsby develop``` same outcome.

Comment: I don't under stand why would it say 15 sec after I changed ```requestConcurrency: 50,``` to this.

Comment: Can you try upgrading your packages and `npm` version as well?

Comment: Same no luck, If I replace the live wordpress site with my local wordpress site it works fine.

Comment: im getting the same issue - it says 'Try lowering process.env.GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD.
It's currently set to undefined.' in my .env file i have it set to 1. any orther ideas to fix this?

Comment: It should be triggered in the develop or build command, not in the environment files

Comment: thanks @FerranBuireu - changing the .env file fixed this for another project. its odd as other users aren't getting this issue (they are on MAC, me Windows). in my gatsby-config, my build command shows: 
'develop: {
          hardCacheMediaFiles: true,
          nodeUpdateInterval: 10000000'. would altering these figures help fix the build issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, it it was fixed after upgrading from Node v10 to v14 and running `npm rebuild`